Why does codeblocks memory dump window not show the error?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


struct train
{
    int id;
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    char destination[21];
};

// сравнивать поезда по каждому из параметров по возрастанию
// ввод: 2 указателя на 2 поезда
// возврат: больше 0, если поезд дальше в списке, меньше 0, если наоборот
int cmpTrains(void const *, void const *);

int cmpTrains(void const *voidTr1, void const *voidTr2)
{
    int res;
    struct train *tr1 = voidTr1;
    struct train *tr2 = voidTr2;
    if ((tr1->hours * 60 + tr1->minutes) -
        (tr2->hours * 60 + tr2->minutes) != 0)
            res = (tr1->hours * 60 + tr1->minutes) -
            (tr2->hours * 60 + tr2->minutes);
    else if (strcmp(tr1->destination, tr2->destination))
        res = strcmp(tr1->destination, tr2->destination);
    else res = tr1->id - tr2->id;
    return res;
}

// Перевести строчку в вехний регистр
// Ввод: указатель на строчку
// Вывод: изменение строчки по указателю
void to_upper(char *);

void to_upper(char *str)
{
    while (*str)
    {
        *str = toupper(*str);
        str++;
    }
    return;
}


int main()
{
// N is amount of trains
    int K, N;
    struct train **ptrs = NULL;
    scanf("%d%d", &K, &N);
// ptrs it is a pointer, that's reffering to other pointers to train objects.
    ptrs = calloc(N, sizeof(struct train*));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        ptrs[i] = (struct train *)malloc(sizeof(struct train));
        scanf("%d %d:%d %s",
              &ptrs[i]->id,
              &ptrs[i]->hours,
              &ptrs[i]->minutes,
              ptrs[i]->destination);
        to_upper(ptrs[i]->destination);
    }
    qsort((void *)ptrs, N, sizeof(struct train *), cmpTrains);
    int cmp = 0, time;
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
    {
        time = ptrs[i]->hours * 60 + ptrs[i]->minutes;
        printf("%03d %02d:%02d %s %d\n", ptrs[i]->id, ptrs[i]->hours,
               ptrs[i]->minutes, ptrs[i]->destination, time - cmp);
        cmp = time;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        free(ptrs[i]);
    free(ptrs);
    return 0;
}

Input in the console was:
4
6
124 12:02 habarovsk
13 12:02 VladiDMir
1 00:01 rOstov
101 23:05 MariuPl
911 17:15 Tagna
921 17:12 Esentuki

I have struct train. And I had placed some of theese "trains" in the heap using double pointer. I decided to debug my project, by using memory dump window. I wanted to find my structures in heap, but I found some obscure behavior of this codeblock function. When I typed in search bar expresion "ptrs.destination", somehow it gets field of object "*ptrs[0]", or as it is an expression "ptrs[0]->destination". I think that ptrs haven't any fields, it is just a pointer.
This is in my opinion more correct query
why there is no error?
I' ve also tried some other expression "ptrs->destination", "(&ptrs)->destination", that seem to be invalid, with all the same result.

Tip: Instead of repeating ptrs[i] a million times, add struct train  *ptr = ptrs[i]; and use ptr instead.

Debuggers are often more permissive about syntax and type-checking than the actual language compiler would be.  Very likely it just interprets .destination affixed to any address as "add 12", since that is the offset of destination in struct train.  Sometimes this flexibility is convenient; other times it just means "garbage in, garbage out".  But my guess is that this sort of behavior is meant as a feature.

Asides: you shouldn't be casting the return from malloc in C; and you don't need to cast ptrs to void* in your call to qsort. As this is an English language site, you might as well remove the Russian (I think) comments. They won't mean much to most here, I suspect.

Why do you dynamically allocate an array of struct Train pointers, then dynamically allocate and assign to each of these pointers? Why not simply dynamically allocate an array large enough to hold N struct Train values in one contiguous block? Note that you never check the return of calloc or malloc nor scanf.

You are correct that ptrs.destination is not a valid C expression. Using it in your program would result in a compilation error.
If the Address box is supposed to accept a C expression, that would be a bug. If. I don't know if that's the case or not.
